# How to read (only read not set ) .env files in Python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

I have `.env` file with following content:

```
DB_URL=''
DB_USER=''
DB_PASSWD=''
DB_NAME=''
COLLECTION_NAME=''
```

**Problem** I want to read this `.env` file in my python program to create connection to `mongodb` but I only found `python` libraries that sets the `env` and read using `os` module. Is there a way to only read the content of `.env`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just open the file and parse it yourself?

```
import pathlib

def read_env(directory):
    env_path = pathlib.Path(directory) / '.env'
    d = {}
    with env_path.open('r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if '=' in line and not line.startswith('#'):  
                # 2nd check allows for files with commented lines, but if you
                # want to have keys starting with a literal '#', just have the 
                # 1st part of the if.
                key, value = line.split('=', 1)
                d[key] = value.strip("'")
    return d
```

Comment: This makes some naive assumptions about the contents of the variables, namely that the value fits on a single line.

Comment: Are you allowed multiline values in `.env` files?

Comment: I think my answer meets the criteria of the question. If you have literal newlines (`\n`) in the string, you could split them yourself, or add an additional check to make it into a list before saving to the dict.

Comment: I can't find a definitive grammar for the files (or does it just assume valid JavaScript string literals?), but it looks like https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/blob/master/lib/main.js assumes that each line contains exactly one key/value pair, so I guess that's the definition. But this answer still misses some corner cases, so I can't recommend writing your own parser from scratch (or at least, verify a custom parser against the tests in the reference parser).

Comment: Sure, this solution isn't great for *all* `.env` files, but if you know exactly what's in the file you've got, it's a bit of a waste to import an entire package for something that's really quite simple. Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 0):

You have two easy options: [dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) and [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html)